# Alternative for a While loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, int

```
   private static void execute(Cheese[] cheeses) {
        int choice;  
        System.out.println("\n\nNow displaying the cheeses");
        choice = getChoice();
        while (true) {
            if (choice == 1)
                sortByName(cheeses);
            else if (choice == 2)
                sortByCost(cheeses);
            else if (choice == 3)
                sortByAge(cheeses);
            else if (choice == 4)
                System.exit(0);
            else
                System.out.print("Invalid entry - please reenter.");
            choice = getChoice();
        }
    }
```

Basically, I am looking for an alternative to this loop. I thought about doing a do loop with an input string but I am having a hard time printing it. Is there a way to have a do while loop that does nothing or asks for an input?

Comment: What improvement are you hoping for with a different kind of loop?

Comment: Sounds like  `System.out.println("\n\nNow displaying the cheeses");` and `choice = getChoice();` should be moved to inside the loop.

Comment: Could you explain what the code shall do? Add some more details please.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `break` in each condition. In order to demonstrate it, I have called `execute()` five times using a loop. To simulate the invocation of different options, I have generated the `choice` randomly.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Call#" + i);
            execute();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void execute() {
        int choice;
        choice = getChoice();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choice: " + choice);
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("sortByName");
                break;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("sortByCost");
                break;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("sortByAge");
                break;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry - please reenter.");
                choice = getChoice();
            }
        }
    }

    static int getChoice() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Call#1
Choice: 6
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 8
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 1
sortByName

Call#2
Choice: 4
Goodbye!

Call#3
Choice: 0
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 5
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 3
sortByAge

Call#4
Choice: 0
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 8
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 0
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 7
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 2
sortByCost

Call#5
Choice: 8
Invalid entry - please reenter.
Choice: 3
sortByAge
```

However, I would use `switch...case` as follows to keep the code clean:

```
private static void execute() {
    int choice;
    choice = getChoice();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choice: " + choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("sortByName");
            return;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("sortByCost");
            return;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("sortByAge");
            return;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            return;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry - please reenter.");
            choice = getChoice();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Hello, I found a way to make it work. However, if I use return, it only allows me to input once. I would like it to ask again (which input). If I use break, it infinitely repeats an output.

Comment: Hello, I was able to get it to work, but how do I make it so that the default line detects an input outside of the cases. Cases 1-3 are obviously the sort, but case 4 for me is to end the program. How do I make it so that the default case is for invalid entry?

Comment: Most likely, you won't need the `for` loop I have used in `main`. I've already mentioned that it is to simulate multiple calls to `execute()`. In your program, the choices which I have generated randomly will be replaced by the user's choice.